# Displaying a month name in an archive

Tags: datetime, postdate, archives

I'm trying to figure out how I can print the month name i.e April in the below. Currently, it's printing the last three months that contain entries.

```
{% set year = craft.request.segment(4) %}
{% set month = craft.request.segment(5) %}

{% set entriesInYear = craft.entries.section('bulletinOnline').limit(null).after(year).before(year+1) %}
{% set groupedEntries =  entriesInYear | group("postDate|date('m')") %}

{% for year, entriesInYear in allEntries | group("postDate.year") %}
    {% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 1 %}

    {% for month, entries in entriesInYear | group("postDate|date('m')") %}

        <a href="{{ url('/archive/')}}/{{ year }}/{{ month }}">
            {% for monthWord, entries in entriesInYear|group("postDate|date('F')") %}
                {{ monthWord }}
            {% endfor %}
            &nbsp;({{ entries|length }})
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Example output:

```
<a href="'/archive/2019/04/">MarchAprilMay(2)</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% set year = craft.request.segment(4) %}
{% set month = craft.request.segment(5) %}

{% set entriesInYear = craft.entries.section('bulletinOnline').limit(null).after(year).before(year+1) %}
{% set groupedEntries =  entriesInYear | group("postDate|date('m')") %}

{% for year, entriesInYear in allEntries | group("postDate.year") %}
    {% for month, entries in entriesInYear | group("postDate|date('m')") %}

        <a href="{{ url('/archive/')}}/{{ year }}/{{ month }}">
        {{ month |date((year + 1) ~ '-' ~ month ~ '-01')|date('M') }}&nbsp;({{ entries|length }})</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```